# Opening a new tab in multiprocess Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, e10s

I am trying to port my existing firefox addon code to the new multiprocess architecture. In my existing code I am able to launch a new tab on the `addon install event` using the code below:

```
function install(data, aReason) {
    if (aReason == ADDON_INSTALL) {
        var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
        var mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
        mainWindow.gBrowser.addTab('http://www.mywebsite.org/install-success-page.html');

    }

    if (aReason == ADDON_UPGRADE) {

        var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
        var mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
        mainWindow.gBrowser.addTab('http://www.mywebsite.org/update-success-page.html');
    }

}
```

After making the changes to bootstrap.js to become `multiprocess firefox` compatible (using help from other extension's code) the addon loads and functions as expected but the above code fails to load a new tab and no error gets displayed in console !!!

Comment: Are you sure this code actually runs? When trying it in Scratchpad this works.

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var Cu = Components.utils;
var { require } = Cu.import(resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open(url);
```

Also this is less likely to break in the future than any platform code.